# How do I express the second derivative of this function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

We have 
$$F(X)=f(x)\psi(x)$$
$$X=\chi(x)$$

I can show that 
$$\frac{dF}{dX}=\frac{1}{\chi^\prime}(\psi f^\prime+f \psi^\prime)$$

But don't know how to express

$$\frac{d^2F}{dX^2}=\text{?}$$

Comment: Do you mean $F(X)=f(X)\psi(X)$? Unclear. Also, what is $y$?

Comment: I find your use of "X" and "x" confusing.  Are they the same?

Comment: Thank you; edited and fixed the expression. $X$  is a function of $x$, $X=\chi(x)$

Comment: I was thinking of $y=f(x)$, but the $y$ is really redundant so I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You differentiate a second time what you have already calculated

$$\frac{d^2F}{dX^2}=\frac{d}{dX}\frac{dF}{dX}=\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dF}{dX}\right )\right )\frac 1{\chi^\prime}$$

Where
$$\frac{dF}{dX}=\frac{\psi y^\prime+y \psi^\prime}{\chi^\prime}$$
Therefore
$$\frac{d^2F}{dX^2}=\frac 1{\chi^\prime}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\psi y^\prime+y \psi^\prime}{\chi^\prime}\right )\right )$$

Note that 
$$\chi'=\frac {dX}{dx}$$

Comment: Note that $X$ and $x$ are not the same, because $X=\chi(x)$

Comment: @user142523  Yes I know I noted that thats why you have that $\chi '$ X is a function of little x

Comment: Do you mean $dX = d(\chi(x)) = \chi^\prime dx$

Comment: yes and thats what you meant too in the first derivative ? @user142523

Comment: Yes, this helped, thank you!

Comment: yw @user142523 .......